# How to get the names of tables of my firebase database in ionic 2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

Is there any solution that allow me to get the name of tables of my database as shown in the picture

[image: database structure]

Comment: There are many, many ways to do so. Did you try anything yet? What's the problem you bumped into?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I will be happy if u help me and share me any links or codes that solve my problem ..

Comment: Please add what you have tried, some code will go a long way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref().once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
        var tableNames = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        console.log(tableNames); // ["answers", "blocks", "chats", "classes"]
    }
});
```

So that gets that whole database and then gets the top level keys from the returned object.

References:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

> In some cases you may want a snapshot of your data without listening
>   for changes, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't
>   expect to change. You can use the `once()` method to simplify this
>   scenario: it triggers once and then does not trigger again.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties

Comment: Perfect answer .. thanks